# Location of the program in the JDK that opens .jar files(double-click)

Tags: jar, java, double-click

I would like to know the LOCATION of the .exe in the JDK that opens .jar files. What I mean is this: Which .exe in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk*version number*\jre\ opens the .jar files, so that they can be opened using a double click? I used to be able to do that, when I newly installed the JDK+JRE. Unfortunately, Nokia PC Suite has made itself the default program for opening .jar files, so that it can install them on my Symbian. Which program do I 'Open With' to get back the old functionality? I already know how to do it from the command line, but this is easier.

Answer (score 1):

There  is no specific program to run jar files.

It is java.exe only with the -jar option

For eg.-->  java -jar "foo.jar"

Right Click on a jar file and go to its properties. Change the default opening program to java.exe.

I hope that should work.

Comment: No, the command window opens and closes immediately. I believe javaw.exe should help, but it doesn't.

Comment: You can try uninstalling the Nokia PC Suite. may be then things go back to the default state.

Answer (score 0):

use javaw.exe if you don't want the command window.

This convention is widely followed by others like perl/python/ruby as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know how frustrating this issue is. I looked all over the internet forums before I finally found the problem...Here is the answer below :

"The root cause for the problem above is, that a program has stolen the .jar association. If you have installed the Java Runtime Environment the first time, the file type called "jar" is assigned to javaw.exe correctly. "jar" is an abbreviation for "java archive" and javaw.exe is the correct program to execute a .jar. However, on Windows any program can steal a file type at any time even if it is already associated with a program. Many zip/unzip programs prefer to do this, because a jar is stored in the .zip format.  If you doubleclick on a .jar, your pack program opens the file, rather than javaw runs the program, because your pack program ignores the meta information which are also stored in a .jar."